# How to compute $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x -1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3}$ without using L'Hospital rule?

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Find the following limit without using L'Hospital rule nor series
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x -1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3}$$
I tried to divide it into two limits such that one of the be
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$$ because i know it solution but i could not do that ?

Comment: For the last question: no, you can't do that

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Isn't $\exp(x)$ defined as $\exp(x):=\sum\limits_{n\geq0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$? Or at least this is how was it defined in our calculus class.

Comment: What is the definition of $e^x$ you are allowed to use? (Because the series *is* a definition for $e^x$, one of)

Comment: @Botond: you may also define the exponential function as $\lim_{m\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{m}\right)^m$ or as the only solution of $f'=f, f(0)=1$. There are many equivalent ways.

Comment: to expand on @YuriyS point, the limit of sum is sum of limits only if both limits exist. The way you broke things up, the other piece diverges

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I know, but they are equivalent, as you've also said. Or is it not allowed to be more challenging?

Comment: @Botond: indeed, once you show it that such definitions are equivalent, you may pick the definition best suited for the task at hand. Truth to be told, I do not love questions asking to prove $X$ *without using $A,B,C,\ldots$ and with your hands tied behind your back*, I believe it is simpler and more instructive to just ask for alternative proofs.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You're right. We were only told not to use the LH's rule before we've actually learned about it.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Would you take a look at my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My attempt of the general case :|

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{x}-\sum\limits^{p-1}_{k=0}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}}{x^{p}}= \frac{1}{p!}. $$

**Using the definition** $e^{x}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$.
we will work the expression
$$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n-\sum\limits^{p-1}_{k=0}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}= $$
for $n>p$, expand $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ by the binomial 
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}(\frac{x}{n})^k -\sum\limits^{p-1}_{k=0}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}=\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}{n \choose k}(\frac{x}{n})^k + {n \choose p}(\frac{x}{n})^p+\sum_{k=p+1}^{n}{n \choose k}(\frac{x}{n})^k}_{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}(\frac{x}{n})^k} -\sum\limits^{p-1}_{k=0}\frac{x^{k}}{k!} =$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}x^{k}\underbrace{({n \choose k}\frac{1}{n^{k}}-\frac{1}{k!})}_{\rightarrow 0} +\underbrace{{n \choose p}(\frac{x}{n})^p}_{\rightarrow  \frac{x^p}{p!}}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-p-1}{n \choose k+p+1}(x)^{k+p+1}\frac{1}{n^{k+p+1}} =$$
we have  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {n \choose k}\frac{1}{n^{k}} =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{k!} (\frac{n}{n})\cdots (\frac{n-k+1}{n})= \frac{1}{k!}$, (every factor has limit 1) so as we take $n \rightarrow \infty $ in the first sum the resultant is zero, dividing the expression by  $x^p$ and applying the limit we have 
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{p!} +\sum_{k=0}^{n-p-1}{n \choose k+p+1}(x)^{k+1}\frac{1}{n^{k+p+1}} = $$
changing the order of the limits
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{p!} +\sum_{k=0}^{n-p-1}{n \choose k+p+1}\underbrace{(x)^{k+1}}_{\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{n^{k+p+1}}  = \frac{1}{p!}$$

so
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{x}-\sum\limits^{p-1}_{k=0}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}}{x^{p}}= \frac{1}{p!}. $$

Comment: I started the same method, however the exchange of the limits proved to be tricky to justify. Still +1 though

Comment: Interchange of limit needs to be justified. Rest of the proof is fine. One can bound the second sum with a function of $x$ which tends to $0$ with $x$ and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

$e^x$ is a (log-)convex function, hence $e^x\geq 1+x$ holds for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. By integrating both sides over the interval $(0,z)$ we get $e^z\geq 1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}$ for any $z>0$ and $e^z\leq 1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}$ for any $z<0$. Performing the same trick twice we get $e^{z}\geq 1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^4}{24}$ for any $z>0$ and the converse inequality for any $z<0$. By squeezing, the wanted limit equals $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: A similar solution (based on the proof of Taylor's Theorem): $e^x - 1 - x - \frac{x^2}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^x e^t (x-t)^2 \, dt$.  Now, if $x>0$, bound $e^t$ between 1 and $e^x$, and you can squeeze $e^x - 1 - x - \frac{x^2}{2}$ between $\frac{x^3}{6}$ and $\frac{x^3 e^x}{6}$.  And similarly for $x<0$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: agreed, this is not really different from proving Taylor's formula through integration by parts, rather than by de l'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 2):

If the limit exists, let it be $L$, by the change of variable $x\to-x$ and taking the average,

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x-\dfrac{x^2}2}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-x}-1+x-\dfrac{x^2}2}{-x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sinh x-x}{x^3}.$$

Now with $x\to3x$, and using $\dfrac{\sinh x}x\to1^*$,

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sinh 3x-3x}{27x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3\sinh x+4\sinh^3x-3x}{27x^3}=\frac19L+\frac4{27}.$$

Hence,

$$L=\frac16.$$

---

$^*$With the same trick,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-x}-1}{-x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sinh x}x=1.$$

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't prove that the limit exists.

Comment: Sorry, i cant understand how did you switch x to -x ? @Yves Daoust

Comment: @HussienMohamed: well, simply by... replacing $x$ by $-x$.

Answer (score 1):

**It's basically the LH's rule, but not the simple application of it:**
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3}$$
Let's call $e^x-x-\frac{x^2}{2}:=f(x)$, so:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x^3}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^3-0}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^3-0^3}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^3-0^3}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{x-0}}{\frac{1}{x-0}}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}}{\frac{x^3-0^3}{x-0}}=\frac{\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}}{\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{x^3-0^3}{x-0}}\stackrel{def}{=}\frac{f'(0)}{(x^3)'(0)}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1-x}{3x^2}$$
And doing it again 2 times you can get:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x}{6}=\frac{1}{6}$$
**Or using $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ :**
$$f(x):=\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}  & \mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
  \frac{1}{2} & \mbox{if } x =0
 \end{array}
\right.$$
Now your limit can be rewritten this way:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\stackrel{def}{=}f'(0)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x(x-2)+x+2}{x^3}$$
So:
$$A:=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x(x-2)+x+2}{x^3}$$
$$B:=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3}$$
From this:
$$A+2B=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(x-2)e^x +x+2+2\left(e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}{x^3}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x\left(e^x-x-1\right)}{x^3}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}=3\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3}$$
So:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^3}=\frac{1}{6}$$